# Post wall - Cancel and Share button frames

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, fbconnect, facebook-canvas

I have integrated Facebook successfully. But the problem is when I am trying to post data into my wall  content is exceeding iPhone screen size. Some data is behind SHARE and CANCEL buttons. How to change frames according to the my content size?

Answer (score 0):

*You can't do anything about it*. Because that view is just a web page loaded dynamically into a *UIWebView*.